# How to hide previous toggle if click on next using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".share").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            id = this.id;
            $("#wraps_"+id).toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="post-add-icon inline-items">
    <svg class="olymp-share-icon share" id="<?php echo $new['post_id']; ?>">
        <use xlink:href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/svg-icons/sprites/icons.svg#olymp-share-icon"></use>
    </svg>
    <span>0</span>
</a>
<div class="wraps" id="wraps_<?php echo $new['post_id']; ?>" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Share Now (Public)</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Share on Friend's Timeline</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In this code, I am simply creating a div which has `id="wraps_<?php echo $new['post_id']; ?>"` which are showing when I click on `share`. Now, what I want when I click first then it shows me `id="wraps_<?php echo $new['post_id']; ?>"` but when I click the second one then the first div must be hidden and second will be open. Similarly with the third. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hide all div of the class name `wraps` then toggle only clicked one.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".share").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('.wraps').hide();
                $(this).closest(".wraps").toggle(); 
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: it works fine but toggle() not working @Mohammad Ali Rony

Comment: @omkara try `$(this).closest(".wraps").toggle();` for toggle. I have updated my answer. please try if any issues let me know.

Comment: Yes, but it's not hidden when I click outside @Mohammad Ali Rony

Comment: @omkara do you want to hide shown div if the user clicks in outside share button inside of the body

Answer (score 0):

Within your click callback function, you can hide all the divs with class `wraps` and then toggle as you are  doing.

```
        $(".share").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            id = this.id;
            $(".wraps").hide(); //Hide all the divs with wraps class.
            $("#wraps_"+id).show(); //Open the one you want.
        });
```